# The benefit of referential transparency in FP

Tags: functional-programming

I was learning functional programming and came across the term referential transparency.

After some research on that, I found out that RT is useful

1. When we want to make our code easier to reason about and read since our function is predictable AND
2. When our function is predictable, it will be of great help to the JIT compiler allowing it to replace the function with its return value(Does it replace the function with its value as long as the function is hot?).

Are both the above statements true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Referential transparency in functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624286/referential-transparency-in-functional-programming)

Answer (score 0):

Referential Transparency means that a function with certain parameters will always return the same result as long as the input parameters are the same, in other words it does not have side effects.
Of course one of the benefits of these is that the code is easier to reason about because the same execution will return the same values so you can change the call to the function by the result it returns.

I suppose this feature is used by many compilers to speed up the execution by making the change, but this depends on the language and the compiler used to translate to byte code, but It little has to do with Functional programming per se.