# Referential transparency in functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, referential-transparency

I am new to JS and was learning functional programming and came across the term "referential transparency". Also, I found this statement "Referential transparency says it's safe to replace a pure function with its value". Does it mean that the use of RT makes it easy for JIT compiler to replace function with its return value as long as function gets hot? Is that true?

Comment: Well, yes - that's a benefit. However, the major reason for RT is to aid with reasoning about the code. As it happens, compilers are *specialised tools* for reasoning about code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

This is a pure function: it will always return the same output for the same input

```js
const even = x => x % 2 === 0;
```

And let's create `isTenEven()` which will check wether `10` is an even number or not:

```js
const isTenEven = () => even(10);
```

Since we're guaranteed that `even(10) === true` will *always* be true then we can indeed replace a function call with a value:

```js
const isTenEven = () => true;
```

And your program *would still work.*™

However you wouldn't be able to do so if `even` wasn't pure!
Here's a silly example: once per month `10` won't be an even number anymore:

```js
const even = x => (new Date()).getDate() === 15 ? false : x % 2 === 0;
```

Perhaps your program is excepting `isTenEven()` to return either `true` or `false`, so forcing it to always assume that it will return `true` *could* lead to unexpected consequences.

Of course in this particular case I'm not sure what those consequences would be but you never know... which is exactly the point.

Comment: :D sorry for the typo. As a completely different side-note about purity and referential transparency - you can purify the impure `even` if you make it receive a date. Then you would get a benefit of optimisation again, since you now have (let's curry it) `date => x => date.getDate() === 15 ? false : x % 2 === 0;` which can easily become `date => date.getDate() === 15 ? () => false : x => x % 2 === 0` and thus save some evaluation.

Comment: @VLAZ I was just trying to show that impure functions are not referentially transparent. It's interesting to show that you can "fix" an impure function but this wasn't the point I was trying to make ;)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - you're right, impure functions lack RT. The point of on how impure functions can become pure again was more of a extrapolation than directly related to your answer. For me personally, the "take an argument to make it pure" thing was a big eye opener when I was looking at pure functions.

Comment: @VLAZ Hm, you still have to feed `even` a date: `even(new Date()) (10)` . Provided the runtime of your programs covers the date switch from 14th to 15th both function calls can yield different result values.

Comment: @VLAZ I think all you can do is `even = x => Defer(() => (new Date()).getDate() === 15 ? false : x % 2 === 0)` where `Defer` is just a type wrapper for a thunk. Now you can use functor/monad/kleisli to combine/compose such deferred computations. Ultimately, however, you have to unleash the effects. In Haskell this happens at runtime, which the compiler implicitly provides for you. In Javascript we have to provide an impure runtime ourselves. The runtime represents the edge of your application so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is exactly an advantage of RT. The compiler can not only inline a function but replace its invocations with the corresponding return value, that is it can eliminate common sub-expressions and rewrite code according to specific rules like you can rewrite formulas in math. This way of reasoning about a program is called equational reasoning and is also very helpful for the programmer.

But RT allows other optimization techniques as well, like lazy evaluation. If you want to automatically delay the evaluation of an arbitrary expression up to the point where its result is actually needed, you need the guarantee that this expression yields the same result no matter when you actually evaluate it. RT gives this guarantee.